# How to add a text field at the top of the columns?

Tags: web2py

I want to add a text field with its value into,

```
jdata = db.executesql("select supplier_name from supplier", as_dict=True)
ret_data = [i.values() for i in jdata]
return dict(jdata=ret_data)
```

For example, the output will be like this:

```
{[['Name', 'Rank'], ['Tom', 1],['Scott', 2],['Joe', 3]]}
```

Thanks !!!

Comment: Your query includes only one column, not two. Also, is it safe to assume you know the column names ahead of time (i.e., you do not need to extract them from the returned result)?

Comment: Thanks  Anthony, I mean I want to append the [['name', 'rank']] field at the beginning of the list.

Comment: Right, but wanted to clarify because your query does not actually select the rank field, so it won't be in the results. Also wanted to make sure this wasn't a generalized problem where you don't know the full list of column names ahead of time and need to get them from the query results.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are OK with a list of tuples rather than a list of lists, you can simply do:

```
    query = 'select name, rank from supplier'
    jdata = [('Name', 'Rank')] + db.executesql(query)
    return dict(jdata=jdata)
```

If you really need a list of lists, then:

```
    jdata = [['Name', 'Rank']] + [list(r) for r in db.executesql(query)]
```

Comment: Sorry, I forget to include the rank field in the query. Any way, thanks very much now I am able to add the Name and Rank fields at the top of the columns.

Comment: So, does the above answer your question, or is there still a problem?

Comment: It worked very well thanks very much. I have another question. How I can convert this json [{"Name": "Tom", "Rank": 2}, {"Name": "Joe", "Rank": 4}] into ['Tom', 'Joe'] and [2,4]